# Which tool can get all windows handle of a browser which is opened?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

For example:
   I **have opened** chrome browser, and **opened** several URL, like google, facebook, w3school ...
Can I use the Selenium to get all Windows Handle? Or Are there other tools I can use to get it?

Comment: Are you asking to use Webdriver to get the handles of windows that you opened manually or the handles of windows opened by calling an instance of webdriver?

Comment: If you have opened all these links in chrome tabs...you will receive only one window handle. But if in other windows use the answer from @master slave..

Comment: I was asking to use Webdriver to get the handles of windows that you opened manually , Are there any functions can achieve that by using Webdriver ? or other tools (maybe not webdriver) can achieve that ?